# Ember render template using yield

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to implement

```
{{#my-custom-component}}
    {{my-other-component field=(some-section someSection "PARAM_1" "PARAM_2") onChangeField=(action 'enable' "PARAM_3")}}
{{/my-custom-component}}
```

So I want to display/render my-other-component inside my-custom-component. So I'll have a `{{yield}}` inside my-custom-component.

Currently with the above, I am getting

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

I suspect I am not passing the params properly.

Comment: can you give more details about `my-custom-component` and `my-component`; there may be some problems related with component lifecycle hook methods within those components; there seems nothing wrong with this template. `some-section` helper code should also be reviewed for infinte looping.

Comment: So someSection is defined in my-custom-component. I want it to be accessible inside my-other-component where I am using yield. So just wanted to know how to pass the values ?

Comment: i still believe we do not have enough information to help you; but I have prepared the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/c68ada11d5083f002bb0d42709806b6c?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-other-component.hbs) for you to illustrate value passing to the inner component via yielding. can you take a look at the twiddle and ask further?

Comment: Hey..Thx a lot for your help. Really appreciate it. We are quite close. Only thing is this entire template is part of my-parent-component & firstName/lastName are properties of this my-parent-component . I want these properties to be rendered/passed to my-other-component (where I'll be doing yield)

Comment: can you take a look at the answer I have provide to your [newer question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45474821/ember-rendering-component-using-yield/45475762#45475762)?