# Ember rendering component using yield

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have a `my-component1.js` defined as below;

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({ 
prop1: 'abc'
})
```

The corresponding template `my-component1.hbs` is as below;

```
{{#my-yield-component2}}
    {{my-other-component3 field=(my-helper prop1)}}
{{/my-yield-component2}}
```

So I want to display/render my-other-component3 inside my-yield-component2 (as I am using yield)

Inside `my-yield-component2`, I have the following;

```
<div>My component with yield</div>
<div>{{yield}}</div>
```

My question is how do I pass/get access to "prop1" which is actually defined in my-component1, but because I am using yield, it would be rendered in my-yield-component2
So I want to know how to pass "prop1" ?

Comment: Nothing wrong, it will work, that's the power of contextual components.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the way `prop1` value of `my-component1` is passed to `my-other-component3`. The context within `my-component1`'s template file is `my-component1` itself; hence `prop1` will be passed from `my-component1` to `my-other-component3` even if `my-other-component3` is rendered within `my-yield-component2`. Please take a look at the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/30b65f24cacb0ea618f609285ead6cb5?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-other-component3.hbs) that illustrates what I explained so far works smoothly.

Regarding value passing from `my-yield-component2` to `my-other-component3` is another story; where you need to `yield` sth. from the template of `my-yield-component2` and pass it to `my-other-component3` as follows:

```
{{#my-yield-component2 as |valueToYield|}}
    {{my-other-component3 field=(my-helper prop1) otherField=valueToYield}}
{{/my-yield-component2}}
```

I have already provided a working [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/c68ada11d5083f002bb0d42709806b6c?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-other-component3.hbs) of what I explained above in [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45462699/ember-render-template-using-yield) of your previous questions.